# How can my question be clearer?

Tags: support, specific-question

Considering that I have had 3 days of a bounty without any answer or comment, then I see DawnKeeper's point in [the question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769496/how-can-i-set-an-opengl-display-to-maximized) as to how it must be unclear.

What I can't understand is why. Or how.

The question clearly states "I would like to maximize a display using OpenGL". Not only am I unsure how better to describe it, but I really can't understand what is so unclear.

How can I make the question clearer?

Comment: could you possibly clarify the difference between 'actually maximizes the screen, not "Fullscreen"'

Comment: @jbutler483 Fair enough, but fullscreen != maximized. I don't get why people can't get that.

Comment: is [this](http://kplayer.sourceforge.net/manual/howto-full-screen.html) what you differentiate them as being?

Comment: @jbutler483 I was literally just about to clarify the OP using similar website definitions. Thanks!

Comment: @jbutler483 `'actually maximizes the screen, not "Fullscreen"'` there is a world of difference between both options. Try setting your browser in fullscreen mode to see the difference.

Comment: the word 'actually' @Renan was what was confusing me. 'Actually maximises the screen' sounds like OP wants it to be fullscreen, not just 'maximised'

Comment: @jbutler483 Oh, whoops.. Nope, I wanted it maximized, not fullscreen.

Comment: I hope now you can see such small vocabulary changes makes quite a bit of difference in meaning - esp. in explaining a problem (DW, i've done the same myself plenty of times before) :P

Comment: So it should have been "Maximizes the window", right?